# What happens when executing a .NET4.0 app in a computer without .NET4.0 installed?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Very simple question, if you compile a program with .NET 4.0 (a program that explicitly uses a feature from .NET 4.0 which is not available in previous framework versions), say a command line program, and you deploy it to a computer that doesn't have .NET 4.0 (let's say it only has .NET2.0 framework).

What happens when you run the .exe from the command line? Is there an exception thrown? Which exception?

I could test myself but I don't have right now a Windows box handy that lacks this framework version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the following error:

[image: To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework: v4.0.30319. Contact your application publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of the .NET Framework.]

Comment: Yes, but after you click OK, you see some output in the console. Can I see the output?

Comment: PS: if you made a commandline app instead of a GUI app, it should show you what's the type of exception thrown.

Comment: @knocte I did a console application app and I still see only this message.. no other errors on command line

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to start the executable as a whole.
You will either get an Exception (in the form of Windows encountered an error.. etc) 
Or you will get a notice that you don't have the right .NET version (not to sure about this last part though..)

Comment: I know that, but I want to know exactly what error message and what exception.

Answer (score 0):

You might get an System.IO.FileLoadException with a message:"Could not load file or assembly ... Version 4.0.0 ..."  when you try to run a .NET 4 program on a machine with a previous version of .NET installed.

Hope this helps...

Comment: You might? I don't want guesses but a real test, thanks :) I want to know exactly what's the type of the exception thrown.